# RHEL, Change Host and Domain Name

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel6, rhel7

I want to change the Hostname and Domain Name of the Server **without using yast** because in this there is no yast or yast2. So please provide me the command for changes this.

I am using **Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8**.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to do several things to change the hostname (some or all of the below depending...)

Edit `/etc/sysconfig/network` and see if there is a `HOSTNAME=` directive, change as appropriate e.g.

```
HOSTNAME=ex1.example.com
```

Issue a `hostname` command as root e.g.

```
hostname ex1.example.com
```

Then restart networking

```
/etc/init.d/network restart
```

You should also take a look at `/etc/hosts` and see if anything there needs tweaking.